# Login options blocked - how to enable

Tags: windows, group-policy, domain, workgroup

I bought a computer (Win10) that I previously used myself from my company.
When I took it home I removed the computer from the domain using a local administrator account.

[image: System properties]

However some settings from the AD seems still to be in effect. How can I enable the blocked Sign-in options?

[image: Sign-in options blocked]

I tried to run this command `gpupdate /force /boot` <kbd>Enter</kbd> but it gave me an error. The problem persists after reboot. The generated report look like this:
[image: Group policy report]
**Blue color**: my computer name
**Green color**: URL containing the name of my company

Comment: Did you also disconnect from the domain by clicking on "Access Work or School" (present in the 2nd image in your post) and clicking "DIsconnect"?

Comment: Try a completely new Windows Account and see if the restrictions still apply. Then ask the Domain Admin to remote in and clear the restrictions.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings I saw that option but choose not to because I believe that is used by Outlook; and I want to be able to read my emails even though it is now my private computer.

Comment: In that case you can try resetting all group policies back to their Windows defaults. In an elevated command prompt enter `RD /S /Q "%windir%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers"` then `RD /S /Q "%windir%\System32\GroupPolicy"` then `gpupdate /force`